# MIPS: Runtime exception

Tags: mips

.data
string: .ascii  "String"

.text
main:

lb $t0, string
lb $a0, 1($t0)

li $v0, 11
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall

I'm trying to run a code to print the first letter of "String", but I'm getting this:
line 8: Runtime exception at 0x00400008: address out of range 0x00000054

Comment: You want the first one to be `la $t0, string` not `lb $t0, string`.  This because your second line dereferences $t0, but it is now a byte not a pointer.  `la` makes a pointer (by address computation and without dereference), whereas `lb` makes a byte loaded from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.data 

string: .ascii "String"

.text main:

la $t0, string      ;gets the address of the string into $t0

lb $a0, 1($t0)      ;loads the "t" in "String" into $a0

li $v0, 11 
syscall

li $v0, 10 
syscall
```

<del>`lb $t0,string` isn't valid MIPS, since the CPU isn't able to load a byte from a constant memory address. (I'm surprised you didn't get an error message for that, actually.)</del>

Comment: It depends on the environment/assembler.  MARS and QtSpim wil allow `lb $0,string`, simply expanding that into two instructions to access a 32-bit absolute address.

Comment: Interesting, I'm used to not being able to do that.